# batch abrir una carpeta protegida

Tags: cmd, batch, .bat

estoy haciendo un .bat que me abra esta carpeta de red es muy sencillo start \192.168.5.23\reportes
pero no se comoo colocar mis credenciales para poder abrirla

OJO no estoy forzando nada, yo tengo usuario y contraseña, pero no se como enviarlo en el bat
Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que la información de esta [página](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/199832-automatically-enter-network-credentials) puede ser de ayuda.

Ahí se da una explicación similar a esta:

```
net use X: "\\Servidor\Usuarios\%username%" /user:Dominio\NombreUsuario "Contraseña"
```

Servidor = El nombre del file server 
Usuarios = Dicrectorio de capeta usuario 
%username% = Tu nombre de usuario 
user = Dominio (MEDERI) \ Nombre de usuario y contraseña (esta última entre comillas)

Espero que eso te pueda ayudar.

Comment: Muchas gracias, funciono correctamente

Answer (score 0):

en lo personal tengo un archivo batch que accede al servidor con mi usuario y contraseña para copiar ciertos archivos.

**El acceso al servidor:**
Net use "\Servidor" user:administrador micontraseña

**Luego las rutas a las carpetas:**
\Servidor\cursos\3roA\

Saludos